# How to add a torque sensor to a 4-wheeled robot?

Tags: gazebo, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to add torque sensors (or get torque feedback) to each wheel of a robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12333/how-to-add-a-torque-sensor-to-a-4-wheeled-robot?/) by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Give [this](http://guardian-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/guardian_controller/src/guardian_controller.cpp) file a look. It is a good example of how to get a joint's commanded effort (aka torque).

Just note, instead of:

```
joint_state_blw_->position_;
```

Use:

```
joint_state_blw_->commanded_effort_;
```

**EDIT**: The reason that I suggested using the pr2_controller_interface is that it's what provides a ROS API to Gazebo. By default, ROS has no access to Gazebo joint information. It's the pr2_controllers that allow us to obtain information and publish messages to Gazebo. By adding such a controller to your robot, you're able to monitor the joints in real time (with respect to Gazebo).

You could always try subscribing to `/joint_states` instead, but I don't know if that will provide the information that you require.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on 2011-12-16**:
I feel like there should be a more straightforward way... a simple function call to get joint commanded effort from within this file.

**Comment by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on 2011-12-16**:
Is there any other way without inheriting from pr2_controller_interface?  I'm actually starting with the first link you sent: http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk/erratic_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin.cpp

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-14**:
Totally my bad. I pasted the wrong link. It should be better now. Sorry about that.

**Comment by [jimmycuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/1433/jimmycuff/) on 2011-12-14**:
I'm not sure I follow.  I don't see anything about joint_state_blw_->position_ or commanded_effor_ in the file.  It looks like the drive controller for the erratic robot that takes in a Twist and converts it to velocity.  Could you expand on your post or point me to the specific function calls?